# How to assign vector elements to get a square wave?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, plot

I have a vector T that is defined as

```
T=zeros(1,4)
```

I want to define T such that `T(1)` and `T(2)` are equal to `1` and `T(3)` and `T(4)` are equal to 0. So that when I plot `T` it looks like a square wave.

I have tried

```
for i=1:2:size(T,2)
   T(i:i+1)=1
end 
figure; plot(T);
```

But this does not give the desired result. It turns out to be [1,0,1,0].

What is the right way to do this assignment?

**To differentiate from questions about plotting square waves:**
I wanted to find out how exactly to create the loop that would plot to look like a square wave, **without** explicitly defining frequency or using the symbolic equation. I would then use this information to modify another script that would do the same thing **but** a larger vector T where the "period" is not the same. Sometimes it is 11s, sometimes 9s and so on.

Comment: LOL... I've just been working on that for code golf ;)

Comment: @beaker is it possible for you to share? :)

Comment: Trying to figure out what's wrong with your code. The first thing is that your `for` loop needs an equal sign: `for i=...`

Comment: sorry thats just a typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The period is 4, not 2:

```
for i=1:4:size(T,2)
   T(i:i+1)=1
end 
figure; plot(T);
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks!! this works!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the signal processing toolbox, an alternative is using the [`square`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/square.html) function:

```
T = (1+square(0:pi/2:3*pi/2))/2 %// 1 1 0 0
```